# how to get the value i passed to my apex endpoint from post request?

Tags: apex, apexrest

im posting json object {"username":'test'} and i cant get it in my apex endpoint

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/login/*')
global class CustomerEndPoint {
     @HttpPost
    global static void loginCustomer() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        Object username= JSON.deserializeUntyped(req.requestBody.toString());
        System.debug(JSON.deserializeUntyped(req.requestBody.toString()));
        List <Customer__c> result = new List<Customer__c>();
        result = [SELECT Id, Name From Customer__c where userName__c=:username];
        if(result.size() == 0){
            res.statusCode = 401;
        }
        else{
             res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
             res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(new List<Object>{result}));
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It would probably be more useful to write a wrapper class to parse your data. JSON.deserializeUntyped in this case would return a `Map<String, Object>`, so you could cast it, but I find it preferable to use concrete data types when possible. Here's how you might do that:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/login/*')
global class CustomerEndPoint {
  class CustomerData {
    string username;
  }
  @HttpPost global static void doPost() {
    try {
      CustomerData data = (CustomerData)JSON.deserialize(
          RestContext.request.requestBody.toString(),
          CustomerData.class
      );
      Customer__c record = [SELECT Name FROM Customer__c WHERE UserName__c = :data.username LIMIT 2]; // Try to find unique record
      RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
      RestContext.response.responseBody =
        Blob.valueOf(
          JSON.serialize(record)
        );
    } catch(QueryException e) {
      RestContext.response.statusCode = 401; // Unique record not found
    }
    } catch(JSONException e) {
      RestContext.response.statusCode = 400; // Bad Request
    }
  }
```

If you'd written your code this way, you'd have received a 400 response, letting you know that your JSON was incorrect; JSON strings are always double-quoted, and never single-quoted, as you've done in your example.

Answer (score 2):

You code gets the value just fine.

Your payload is incorrect:

> {"username":'test'}

Should be: `{"username":"test"}`

Use quotes not single quote mark

**Code used to test**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/login/*')
global class CustomerEndPoint {
     @HttpPost
    global static void loginCustomer() {

        System.debug(JSON.deserializeUntyped(req.requestBody.toString()));

    }
}
```

**Endpoint used**

```
https://xyz.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/login
```

**Debug**

> 39.0 >APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO 09:04:07.0
> (442466)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|00523000000iVTN|xxx@gmail.com|Pacific Standard Time|GMT-08:00 09:04:07.0
> (517797)|EXECUTION_STARTED 09:04:07.0
> (522993)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p2300000095O4|CustomerEndPoint.loginCustomer 09:04:07.0
> (2784724)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|{username=test} 09:04:07.3
> (3454050)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE 09:04:07.3
> (3454050)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
>
> Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
> Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
> Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
> Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
> Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
> Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
> Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
> Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
> Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
> Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
> Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
> Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10
>
> 09:04:07.3 (3454050)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END
>
> 09:04:07.0 (3497651)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|CustomerEndPoint.loginCustomer 09:04:07.0
> (4512201)|EXECUTION_FINISHED